# mysql で完全に復元可能な形で、 csv を export/import するには？

Tags: mysql

MySQL に対して、 SELECT INTO OUTFILE を、 FIELDS TERMINATED BY と OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY を指定しながら実行することで、 csv を出力できるかと思います。

しかし、この csv は、内部の文字列にフィールドセパレーターや ENCLOSE のための文字列が含まれていた場合、 csv としては正しい形式として出力はされないと思っています。

#### 質問

- MySQL サーバーに対して、完全に復元可能な形で、 csv を export/import する方法は一般的にどのようなものになりますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qiita](https://qiita.com/tasmas256/items/ec7e23278ee2b40aad79) を漁ってみたところ、
`OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` を用いると、出力される`csv`は
データーにエンクロージャーが含まれている場合、その文字がエスケープされて出力されるようですので、大丈夫なのではないでしょうか？